# Resolving Flutter Card Layout Issue

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, layout, responsive

The card that I have coded works perfectly fine when a screen is in normal size, I am just testing UI with a bit smaller screeens.
The UI is actually just fine, but not responsive and kind to different screen sizes.

```
Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: Get.height * 0.15,
                        width: Get.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          color: const Color(0xFFF6F9FF),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: const Color(0xFFA5C3FF),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 3,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/pubg_demo.png",
                                    height: Get.height * 0.26,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 4,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 12, horizontal: 12),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    customTextWidget(
                                      text: "PUBG Mobile",
                                      color: ColorConstants.blackColor,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ),
                                    customTextWidget(
                                      text: "\$10-\$100",
                                      color: ColorConstants.blackColor,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                    Flexible(
                                      child: customTextWidget(
                                        text:
                                            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy. ",
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        color: const Color(0xFF787D87),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Obx(() {
                                return SizedBox(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 21, horizontal: 12),
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              cartController.addQuantity();
                                            },
                                            child: Container(
                                              color:
                                                  const Color(0xFF6F60B1),
                                              height: 30,
                                              width:
                                                  30, // Set a specific width for the container
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                                  "assets/svgs/ADD.svg",
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Spaces.extraSmallH,
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Container(
                                            child: customTextWidget(
                                              text: cartController
                                                  .quantityCard.value
                                                  .toString(),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Spaces.extraSmallH,
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              cartController
                                                  .removeQuantity();
                                            },
                                            child: Container(
                                              color:
                                                  const Color(0xFF717171),
                                              child: const Align(
                                                child: Icon(
                                                  Icons.remove,
                                                  size: 18,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

this is my code and below are the screens of normal sizes and smaller sizes.
[image]

and this is a normal phone size [image]